# How to view an arrays result inside controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am stuck in getting a value from model and process it in controller. I am new to codeigniter. My model code is this:

```
    public function display_cat_courses($value)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courses_tbl');
        $this->db->join('course_category_tbl', 'courses_tbl.course_category_id = course_category_tbl.id');
        $this->db->where('course_category_id', $value);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

And my controller is this:

```
    public function view()
    {   
        $this->load->model('Category_model');
        $cat_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['category']=$this->Category_model->display_cat_courses($cat_id);
    }
```

I just want to get a column value from course_category_tbl and store that inside an array as array element to process that later.Model works fine but in my controller I want to store "course_type" which is a column in course_category_tbl. How to get it.

Comment: few things to consider, are there duplicate course types? is there any reason why you don't do a select for that particular column?

Comment: No duplicate course types are there it is juat a searching of courses according to their course_category_id

Comment: So why not just do a select? Do you plan on using this function for a situation where you need the other columns as well?

Comment: Yes This will display all the courses which is of same category.

Comment: then the array_column answer is your best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are succesfully getting all datas in array format from model in controller and you only want one field data from array that you need to use for some purpose.For that,you can make use of

```
$field_values_array = array_column($whole_array, 'field_name');
print_r($field_values_array );
```

From this code,you will get all values of that column field in array Format,and later you can pass it to view for further proccessing.

Comment: I am successfully getting all the records. I just want to view all the elements that are present in $data['category'] array inside controller how to do that.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#creating-loops

Answer (score 1):

You can select required column only:

```
$this->db->select('course_category_tbl.course_type');
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I want. My problem is something different.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one row that you'll get by passing the category ID then in the model in place of

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

you can add put

```
$this->db->row_array()
```

and this will give you a one dimensional array and then from the result `$query` you can access the desired elemnt by passign the index.
E.g
`$query['course_type']` will give you course type

Comment: Thanks but I want multiple columns. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: @Sagar In that case you can fetch the result as you are doing i.e `$query = $this->db->get();` and then do a foreach on the result data `$query` and then get the desired index.

Comment: Ya I did the same.